# Android - Increasing the size of the button in an Alert Dialog

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I want to adjust the font size of the buttons (positive, negative, and neutral) in an AlertDialog in Android. So far I've only seen font size adjustments for the title and the message of an AlertDialog.

Here is the code I use to create the dialog:

```
public void showPopUp(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main);
    pvuDB.open();
    imageDB.open();


    dialog.setTitle("Select Unit and Quantity of Variant");

    //set drawables ArrayList here
            //here I'm just fetching image paths because my dialog has a listView
            //made up of images in its message
    drawables = imageDB.fetchDialogImages(getIntent().getStringExtra("productName"), 
            pvuDB.getVariantOfProduct(getIntent().getStringExtra("productName"), variantPosition));
    imageDB.close();

        //R.layout.dialog_main is just a plain white layout with a listView
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_main, null);

    //get unit details here
    final ArrayList dialogList = getDialogData();
    pvuDB.close();

    final ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
    customListAdapterDialog = new CustomListAdapterDialog(OrderForm.this, dialogList);

    lv.setAdapter(customListAdapterDialog);

    //TODO this one is the dialog that sets the quantity
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, final int position, long id){
            //Long listView onclick function here
    });

    dialog.setView(view);
    dialog.show();
}
```

I know I can just go and use a Custom Dialog but that would be too much for my purposes since I'm only adjusting the font size of the button.

Is it possible to increase/decrease the font size of the button in an AlertDialog without using a Custom Dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add these style to styles.xml

```
  <style name="AlertS" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
 </style>
```

after this, write this code on creating the alert dialogue.

```
 ContextThemeWrapper con = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.AlertS );
 AlertDialog.Builder bui = new AlertDialog.Builder( con );
```